# Facebook login on unity android app problems

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, unity-game-engine

I am testing an android app I created in Unity on my Galaxy S4 and I successfully log in, and everything works great!  However, while changing no settings, I test my app on a Moto X device, and when I click login button and accept permission request.  Nothing happens, and I do not log in.

Is their something specific I need to provide to handle different android devices to successfully use the facebook sdk?

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It should work regardless of the device

Just make sure you are asking for read only permissions during FB login (e.g. email permission)... after successfully getting the read permission then you should be able to ask for write permissions such as uploading photos...etc

switch to development build and see what the android console log show? you should at least get some errors

Comment: I have publish actions so ill take that out of fb.login. Also is it possible that the keyhash I gave facebook is wrong and it only works for my phone and not others?

Comment: What are you are app settings (facebook app page) set to? did you make the app available for public? check "Status and Review" section there should be a button in the top... if you dont want to make it public yet then you need to add your testers in "Roles" section

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have solution?